# Undefined binding(s) while executing SELECT query

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I am using a Bookshelf `refresh` method to refresh a model but I am having a weird problem here. I have two tables `device` and `subscription` and they have one to one relationship. I have a method (lets call it foo) in which I am trying to `refresh` a `subscription` model. Now, I have two different scenarios when I am calling `foo()`.

**1**

In this scenario, I call `foo()` with a `subscription` model which looks something like this

```
{ user_id: 10289,
  id: 1179,
  more columns...
}
```

and when I try to refresh this `subscription` model it works as expected and I don't get any errors.

**2**

In this scenario, I fetch the `device` first along with `subscription` like so `Device.forge().fetch({withRelated: ['subscription']})`. Then I call `foo()` with `subscription` model which looks something like this

```
{ user_id: 10289,
  id: 1179,
  more columns...,
  device: {
     id: 17093,
     user_id: 10289,
     subscription_id: 1179,
     more columns...
  }
}
```

When I try to `refresh` a `subscriotion` model here I get an error

`Undefined binding(s) detected when compiling SELECT query: select "subscriptions".* from "subscriptions" where "subscriptions"."id" = ? and "subscriptions"."id" = ? limit ?`

For some reason, the generated query is expecting two `subscription_id`'s in `where` clause and one of them is `undefined`.

My question is why does query has two `subscription_id`'s in the second scenario? Why `refresh` works as expected when there is no `device` model present along with `subscription` model?

Any help clarifying this is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What version of Bookshelf are you using?

Comment: @devius I am using 0.10.4 version of Bookshelf.

Comment: @devius Please check this same issue opened by my colleague on GitHub - https://github.com/bookshelf/bookshelf/issues/1844